# how to "gmake 32bit USE_JEMALLOC=yes" for redis work on FreeBSD 8.1 64 bit

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, redis, freebsd, gnu-make

I can't compile 2.4 redis 32bit on FreeBSD 64 bit. I've already done :

```
cd /usr/lib32
ftp ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/8.1-RELEASE/lib32/
prompt
mget *.*
quit
sh install.sh
csup -h cvsup.freebsd.org /usr/share/examples/cvsup/standard-supfile
cd /usr/src; make build32 install32; ldconfig -v -m -R /usr/lib32
```

but when try to compile redis i get:

```
#gmake 32bit USE_JEMALLOC=yes
.....

MAKE linenoise
gmake[3]: Entering directory `/usr/home/7k7ktest/redis/deps/linenoise'
cc -m32 -c -Wall -W -Os -g linenoise.c
cc -m32 -c -Wall -W -Os -g example.c
cc -m32 -Wall -W -Os -g -o linenoise_example linenoise.o example.o
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
gmake[3]: *** [linenoise_example] Error 1
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/7k7ktest/redis/deps/linenoise'
gmake[2]: *** [dependencies] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/7k7ktest/redis/src'
gmake[1]: *** [32bit] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/7k7ktest/redis/src'
gmake: *** [32bit] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to point the compiler to the 32 bit libraries for this to work out. You can do so by prefixing the gmake command with:

CC="cc -B/usr/lib32"

Compiling Redis will be successful, but it is very buggy. Tests fail and Redis segfaults in numerous situations. I'd advise just to stick with 64-bit Redis on amd64 FreeBSD, or 32-bit Redis on i386.

Another comment: the standalone jemalloc library that Redis uses doesn't build on FreeBSD. You can use the default allocator in both FreeBSD and NetBSD, since they use an earlier version of jemalloc by default.